# Email Address should not be updated in ALL SUB

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

We are sending email communication to the customers already present in 'All Subscribers'. We intend to use the same Subscriber Key but may send to different email address. The requirement is that the Email address in 'All Subscribers' for that subscriber should not be updated. We are sending via Journey Builder.
Is there any work around for this? [image]

Answer (score 3):

When configuring your Email Send activity in JB, you can select the expected behaviour in context of All Subscribers list. This option is however only available in the recently introduced Transactional Journeys:
[image]

You do it in **Activity Summary > Delivery Options.**
Once you set it to "Only add new subscribers", then the email address connected to an existing Subscriber Key will not be updated.

Unfortunately, in the regular journeys, this setting is not available, and it is not possible to avoid updating All Subscribers in regular journeys.

Comment: So the email will be sent to email in the DE, if it's not the one linked to the sub_key in all sub?

Comment: Yes, @nandhiniramchandran - that’s the advantage of sending it from JB

Comment: But I don't find that option in my account

Comment: @nandhiniramchandran - please update your question with more details, supported with screenshots of your email activity configuration

Comment: I have added the screenshot, this is my problem I already have the Sub_key linked to different email address in all sub. For this email send, i need to use different email with same sub_key as that in all sub but it should not be updated in all sub.

Comment: Do we need any special permissions to get the options which you have specified? @Lukas Lunow

Comment: And again @LukasLunow with some hidden features all over the place ;) May this be an enterprise licence feature and not usuable in corporate or lower?

Comment: Not at all, @JohannesSchapdick - only a Danish brainfart. This option is only available in the new transactional journeys. In regular journeys - you can't avoid updating all subs :-(

Comment: So,it will not suit my problem :-( i want to trigger a journey via automation.

Comment: So just out of curosity, why do you not want the email_address not updated in All Subscribers?  Considering, if the user unsubscribes using the email client functionality, what would happen? Also in case of bounces. @nandhiniramchandran

Comment: For this send the email address for the sub are different coming from different source we want the original email to be maintained in all sub for other send @swati mishra

Comment: The only solution could be to take a backup of those subscribers and then import back in all subscribers once the email is sent @nandhiniramchandran